# Jsonapi.org and Play Framework

Tags: json, playframework-2.0

Are there any support for jsonapi.org JSON schema in Play Framework? 
If no, any good third party Java libraries which provides this support?

Comment: In what way do you want to use it? Auto-generation of a schema from your models? Or something else?

Comment: Have a structured well defined way to format the JSON. As I understood it jsonapi.org have my data in a "data" properties, but it addition it add some meta data to my JSON

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at:

https://github.com/zalando/scala-jsonapi

some example use cases:

https://github.com/zalando/scala-jsonapi/blob/master/src/test/scala/org/zalando/jsonapi/json/ExampleSpec.scala

Alternatively, you could try to do this yourself in a standard way tailored to your use case using your own case classes and Play JSON combinators (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators) according to the JSON API spec - I don't think it would be too much overhead and you will get more compile-time checks.